# Xamarin forms (Visual Studio) - Error while loading project after updating to Xamarin and jdk 1.8

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After updating Xamarin for Visual Studio to v'4.3.0.789' and jdk 1.8. I am getting this error. I have tried all possible way but unable to resolve.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     An error occurred trying to install required android components
>   on Project 'CrossPlatformApp2.Android'. Project
>   'CrossPlatformApp2.Android' requires the following components
>   installed on your machine:  Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
>   JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.3.0/appcompat-v7-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.3.0/appcompat-v7-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/23.3.0/mediarouter-v7-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/23.3.0/mediarouter-v7-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/23.3.0/mediarouter-v7-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>
> Please double-click here to install it.
>
> Intallation Errors: XA5209 Unzipping failed. Please download
>   'https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip:m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.3.0/appcompat-v7-23.3.0.aar'
>   and extract it to the
>   'C:\Users\prashantvarma\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded'
>   directory XA5209 Reason: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\prashantvarma\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4'
>   because it is being used by another process. XA5207 Please install
>   package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK
>   installer. Java library file 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\classes.jar' doesn't exist.
>   XA5207 Please install package:
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer.
>   Java library file 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\classes.jar' doesn't exist.
>   XA5207 Please install package:
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer.
>   Java library file 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar'
>   doesn't exist.            0

However, my old application (created in old Xamarin version) is able to run.

Comment: Working with Xamarin for 1,5 years now. A clean reinstall did help sometimes.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am able to resolve this issue simply by uninstalling Xamarin and installing again the older version (v4.2.1) that shows in Visual studio Professional 2015 Setup.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this error as well. Try the underlying fix I wrote and use myself.

---

If you get multiple errors when trying to build the project (e.g. ~14 errors) which state that the unzipping of packages failed and that you will have to do it manually, then do the following:

- Go to the path stated in the error
- Go a folder (or 2) higher until you see a folder called "zips".
- Delete all the content in that (“zips”) folder and retry building.

The build will take a bit longer, so have some patience.
This error is caused by a corrupted zip of a needed package in the build, mostly caused by aborting a build. Deleting the files will force the compiler to redownload the packages which will fix the corrupted zips issue.